# How to create horizontal slide pages in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In bootstrap im trying to use this data-slide-index="" to work horizontal slide but it's working

How to create horizontal slide pages in bootstrap like this site http://designmodo.com/startup/ click on arrow to down the page, (Framework Tab).

Comment: That's just a full-width carousel. [Boostrap Carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/). With Bootstrap you aren't limited to just putting an image in the item div. You can put anything you want.

Comment: Sir do you have any example for this type of bootstrap carousels.... im really new to it and im trying to work such style in my new project...

Comment: I'm a ma'am, and yes. I linked to it in my previous comment. Click the blue text.

Comment: Thanks a lot Maam, i checked the Bootstrap Carousal as you given in url, i understand how to make it working, my simple problem is how to move those radio button to top left corner and i want those radio buttons in different way... any help???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to change the radio button position, you will need to edit the `.carousel-indicators` CSS. An override is recommended rather than changing the Bootstrap code (and if regular overrides don't work, you might need to have an `!important` declaration.

To move the position, you would change `left`. To make it appear to be more within the container at to the top using [the example provided](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/), this would work:

`.carousel-indicators{
left: 10%;
top: 90px;}`

It's already absolute positioned so you can fine-tune to your specifications. `.carousel-indicators li` and `.carousel-indicators .active` create the buttons, so if you want to change how they look, that is where you would do so.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!.... this is the exactly correct! what im looking for the answer about carousel and indicators and more on background and text left side with button Read More, i will take care of those thanks a lot Maam for your kind response....

Comment: Aibrean - Maam do you know how to create a single page WordPress Theme.. and how to add pages - they can show in front page of index all multiple pages with scrolling with id in menu... waiting for your response maam thanks a lot for your previous help it really helped me a lot.

Comment: Yes I do. I've put together a few sites that utilize them. I can't put my answer in here because there isn't enough room. You can get my info here and email me: https://github.com/aibrean.